# How can i make the strcmp function check each line in an archive?

Tags: c, crud, registration

I'm doing a program in C where users need to be able to registrate and then log in. While i was doing that i just noticed that the program was only able to verify the first user that registrate, and not all the others. Now, i need to make this `strcmp` function to be able to check every line of the archive and see if the users credentials match with any of the lines of the archive. Honestly, i tried it in different ways but i just don't know how to do this. Can anyone give me a help, any idea? My registrate function:

```
void cadastrar_user() {
FILE *fp;
struct usuario_t usuario;
int i = 1;
memset(&usuario,0,sizeof(struct usuario_t));

printf("\n ----Cadastro de usuario----");
printf("\n\n Insira um login> ");
scanf("%s", &usuario.login);
printf("\n Insira uma senha> ");
scanf("%s", &usuario.senha);

fp = fopen("login", "a+");
fwrite(&usuario, sizeof(struct usuario_t), 1, fp);
fputs("\n", fp);
fclose(fp);
printf("\n");
printf("\n ---- Usuario cadastrado, redirecionando para login! ----");
login();
```

}

And bellow, my login function:

```
int login(){
FILE *fp;
struct usuario_t usuario;
fp = fopen("login","rb");
memset(&usuario, 0, sizeof(struct usuario_t));

fread(&usuario, sizeof(struct usuario_t), 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
if(!strcmp("", usuario.login)){
printf("\n ----Cadastro nao encontrado, redirecionando para cadastro!----\n");
cadastrar_user();}

 else {
        char login[LOGIN_MAX];
        char senha[SENHA_MAX];
        printf("\n Login> ");
        scanf("%s", &login);
        printf(" Senha> ");
        scanf("%s", &senha);

        if (!strcmp(login, usuario.login) && !strcmp(senha, usuario.senha)) {
            printf("\n Bem vindo %s!\n", usuario.login);
            menu_crud();
        }

        else {
            printf(" \n----Usuario ou senha invalidos!----\n");
            printf("\n  Tente novamente! Redirecionando para a pagina inicial\n\n");
            main();
        }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Calling `main()` directly is _**undefined behavior**_ your program could do anything.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Only in C++, it's allowed in C but not a good habit.

Comment: When using `scanf` and the `%s` format specifier, the pointer-to operator `&` is almost always wrong. No matter if you have an array or a pointer it will result in the wrong type being passed to the `scanf` function, leading to *undefined behavior*. The `%s` format expects a `char *` argument, which an array will *decay* to (i.e. if `usuario.login` is an array then using it as-is will be the same as `&usuario.login[0]`).

Comment: Also if you want to read and write raw structures from or to a file, then you need to open the file in *binary* mode. Otherwise there could be unintended consequences as the reading and writing may translate things like the newline.

Answer (score 1):

You need a *loop* to read all records from the file, and compare against the user input.

Something like:

- Get user login name and password
- If file doesn't exist or is empty then call the register function, and return
- Otherwise open the file
- For each record in the file (a loop)
- Read and compare against the user input
- If found, then return from the function with the record
- If the loop ends then the user wasn't found, so call the register function